# How to open Russian-language PDFs for NLTK processing

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, nltk, pypdf, cyrillic

I'm trying to extract text from a pdf file in Russian, and use this text as data for tokenisation, lemmatisation etc. with NLTK on Jupyter Notebook. I'm using PyPDF2, but I keep running into problems.

I am creating a function and passing to it the pdf as the input:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def getTextPDF(pdfFileName):
    pdf_file = open(pdfFileName, "rb")
    read_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

    text = []

    for i in range(0, read_pdf.getNumPages()):
        text.append(read_pdf.getPage(i).extractText())
    return "\n".join(text)
```

Then I call the function:

```
pdfFile = "sample_russian.pdf"
print("PDF: \n", myreader_pdf.getTextPDF(pdfFile))
```

But I get a long pink list of the same error warning:

```
PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header b'1' b'0' [pdf.py:.....]
```

Any ideas would be very helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is just a warning you can ignore it if it's working. Does your code return something? If not, does it work on other files? It is – alas – a common misconception that *all* text can *always* be read from *all* PDFs; your file may be one where you cannot.

Comment: No, it doesn't return anything else. Just whitespace. And I don't think it has much to do with Cyrillic script (I know decode("utf-8") is necessary, I just can't figure out where to put it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2 and pypdf. Please move to pypdf:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```

See https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extract-text.html

We improved text extraction a lot in 2022.